# Why does this JSON file data not save correctly into Java objects?

Tags: java, json, gson

I have to deserialize the following JSON:

```
{
  "locations":
  [
    {
      "name": "Sagrada Família",
      "coordinates": [2.174400, 41.403475],
      "description": "Famosa església inacabada iniciada la dècada de 1880, amb un museu i vistes de la ciutat.",
      "architect": "Antoni Gaudí i Cornet",
      "inauguration": 2026
    },
    {
      "name": "Plaça Catalunya",
      "coordinates": [2.170079, 41.386878],
      "description": "La plaça de Catalunya és la més cèntrica i gran de les places de Barcelona. Constitueix el punt d'unió \nentre el nucli antic de la ciutat i l'Eixample. D'aquí parteixen importants vies de la ciutat com la Rambla, \nel passeig de Gràcia, la rambla de Catalunya, les rondes de la Universitat i de Sant Pere i el carrer Pelai, \nigual com l'avinguda del Portal de l'Àngel, la gran artèria comercial de la ciutat, i antiga porta de \nles muralles."
    },
    {
      "name": "Can Punyetes",
      "coordinates": [2.159704, 41.398694],
      "description": "Restaurant de cuina catalana.",
      "characteristics": ["Acollidor", "Informal", "Està bé per als nens"]
    },
    {
      "name": "Traphouse",
      "coordinates": [2.165150, 41.405290],
      "description": "Casa reconeguda principalment per les cançons que es composen aquí. Els veïns són una delícia, \nmai es queixen del xivarri que hi ha."
    },
    {
      "name": "Lloc de Socis",
      "coordinates": [2.166506, 41.402617],
      "description": "Si alguna vegada vols ser soci d'un club on la gent s'ho passa molt bé, aquest és el lloc \non has d'anar. No te'n penediràs!"
    },
    {
      "name": "Adoquín Square",
      "coordinates": [2.172804, 41.388794],
      "description": "Plaça coneguda pels jocs lúdics que s'organitzen. Es poden fer des de partides de Minecraft fins al \njoc de la manguera d'aigua. També s'ofereix servei de barbacoa."
    },
{
      "name":"Hotel W",
      "coordinates": [2.190109, 41.368762],
      "description": "Hotel més famós de Barcelona definit per la seva forma de vela. A dins t'hi pots trobar de tot\n menys Barcelonins. Ha estat galardonat amb el premi per més mites per metre quadrat de la ciutat, \nprecedit per La Salle Campus Barcelona",
      "stars": 5
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see, this JSON contain different objects from class `Location`, but, a location can be an `Hotel`, a `Restaurant` or a `Monument` depending of the atributes of each location on the JSON. Because of this, I have implemented the following classes:

```
public class Location {

    private String name;
    private double[] coordinates;
    private String description;
}

public class Hotel extends Location {

    private short stars;
}

public class Monument extends Location {

    private String architect;
    private short inauguration;
}

public class Restaurant extends Location {

    private String[] characteristics;
}
```

And also a class called `DataModel` to save all the locations from the JSON:

```
public class DataModel {

    private Location[] locations;
}
```

I thought executing this code to load the data into the objects would be correct:

```
try {

    reader = new JsonReader(new FileReader(path));
    dataModel = gson.fromJson(reader, DataModel.class);

 } catch(FileNotFoundException e) { System.out.println("Error"); }
```

But it just saves all the data in `Location` objects instead of in the sub-objects of `Location` omitting sub-object variables.

How would be the proper way to do this?

Comment: You aren't representing the subclasses in your JSON, only their instances. e.g. you don't have Hotel with stars inside, you only have stars as if it were an instance to Location

Comment: How do you expect the parser to know what the difference between a hotel, monument, or restaurant is? You'll need to write a custom deserializer. See https://futurestud.io/tutorials/gson-advanced-custom-deserialization-basics

Comment: I thought the gson would notice the classes extending the main class Location and it's atributes

Comment: Unfortunately not. GSON has no knowledge that those classes even exist.

Answer (score 0):

"I thought gson would notice the classes extending the main class Location and it's attributes"

No. Using the stars instance reference as I mentioned in the comments, the way gson sees it you effectively are saying that stars is an instance to locations. In reality, you are trying to say that the Location object has an instance of the class Hotel, which contains stars.

Taking the example from [here](https://www.javaguides.net/2018/10/gson-serializing-inner-classes-example.html) - which would be great to checkout.

```
{
  "value1": "value1",
  "value2": "value2",
  "innerClass": {
    "value3": "value3",
    "value4": "value4"
  }
}
```

As you can see, the outer class has three attributes: value1, value2, and an object called innerClass which contains its own instances. You are telling the deserializer that when it is in the outerclass, to look for value1, value2, and the innerclass. If you presented it with value3 and value4, it wouldn't know what to do with them because it was never told about them; it only knows about value3 and value4 when it is in the innerclass.